# Microsoft Bot Framework with python trouble running

Tags: python, botframework

I am trying out the framework sample from here https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python
But when I run it and access the http://localhost:9000 I get an error message:
405: Method Not Allowed

Do I hace to modify something from the code to run? or create a bot service and provide it with the keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine on my side. According to your description, it seems that you may directly request on browser to the address `http://localhost:9000` via Get method, which could raise this issue.

You can use [Bot Framework Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to test and debug the bot application on local.

Comment: Gary is right, another situation when you would receive this error message would be when you **do** have the bot registered and are attempting to talk to the bot via the Test in Web Chat pane in Azure, as here a ping is sent via the OPTIONS method. To get around this, all you need to do is provide method handlers, depending on which methods you wish to support.